# JQuery set formatted text of a nested input element conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm starting off with JQuery with ASP.Net MVC and struggling to achieve the below requirement:

For all `input` elements with `type = text` contained in `td` elements with a particular `id`(myId), I need to write a function which would format the number contained in that particular text box(comma separated and with decimals) when the focus is removed / form is saved and set it. Currently, it reflects properly only when the page is reloaded.

[image]

Till now, I have managed to write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr td[id*=myId] input[type=text]').on("focusout", function (element) {
            console.log(this);
            //$(element).fval($.myFormat.format(element.value));
            });
    });
```

where `myFormat.js` is a JavaScript file which contains a method called `format()` to format values(comma separated and with decimals). E.g: `$.myFormat.format(232038232233)` gives `"232,038,232,233.00"`

Note: The commented out line throws an error.

Any help whatsoever would be beneficial.

**UPDATE**
I tried the below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr td[id*=myId] input[type=text]').on("focusout", function (element) {
                console.log(this);
                $(this).val($.myFormat.format(this.value));;
                });
        });
```

I gave `437427244` as the input value, but unfortunately the output remains unformatted(infact when I look at the console for the value of `this, I can see that the old value(the value which was there before my change) is still showing.

```
    <input class="DataOriginUserInput numeric" data-formatinfo="n2" 
data-formattype="1" dataorigvalue="578,575,979,700.00" 
data-val="true" id="myId_11" name="..." 
type="text" value="578,575,979,700.00">
```

Comment: `throws an error` what error? `fval is not a function` by any chance ?

Comment: What you are calling `element` is actually the event object. Try `$(this).val(...)`

Comment: @JeremyThille  I have updated the post; please have a look

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the post; please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `$.myFormat` plugin comes from so just tossed together  quick thousands formatter and targeted the classes

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {   
    return x.toString().replaceAll(',','').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

$('input.DataOriginUserInput.numeric').on("focusout", function (event) {
     $(this).val(numberWithCommas(this.value))
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>  <input class="DataOriginUserInput numeric" data-formatinfo="n2" 
data-formattype="1" dataorigvalue="578,575,979,700.00" 
data-val="true" id="myId_11" name="..." 
type="text" value="578,575,979,700.00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="DataOriginUserInput numeric" type="text" id="myId2" value="13456899999"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="DataOriginUserInput numeric" type="text" id="myId3" value="444444444444444.99"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be supported in older browsers:

```js
$('input[id*=myId][type=text]')
  .on("focusout", function(element) {
    let ns = this.value.replace(/,/g, '');
    let n = Number.parseFloat(ns);
    let outn = n.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });
    console.log(ns, n, outn);
    $(this).val(outn);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="DataOriginUserInput numeric" data-formatinfo="n2" data-formattype="1" dataorigvalue="578,575,979,700.00" data-val="true" id="myId_11" name="..." type="text" value="578,575,979,700.00">
```